# Как редактировать записи в Sqlite телеграм бота Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite, aiogram, sqlite3

Есть бот на aiogram с бд sqlite. Через  машину состояний я создаю объект в базе данных . Потом могу вывести их всех . Но как реализовать редактирование объектов ? В данном случае это пицца, у неё есть фото, название, цена и описание. Как можно реализовать форму редактирования или каким образом вводить новые значения. Для примера изменить цену. Или так не делают на практике ? Возможно есть бот и сайт пицерии и они имеют общюю БД? Буду благодарен за любую информацию.

```
class FSMAdmin(StatesGroup):
    photo = State()
    name = State()
    description = State()
    price = State()


@dp.message_handler(text='Загрузить')
async def cm_start(message : types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:    
        await FSMAdmin.photo.set()
        await message.reply('Загрузить фото ')



async def load_name(message : types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:      
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['name'] = message.text
        await FSMAdmin.next()
        await message.reply('Описание:')    



async def load_description(message : types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['description'] = message.text
    await FSMAdmin.next()
    await message.reply('Укажите цену:')    



async def load_price(message : types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        if message.text.isdigit(): 
            data['price'] = float(message.text)
        else:
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'укажите корректную цену ')   
    await sqlite_db.sql_add_command(state)
    await state.finish()
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Добавлено.') 

#Это sqlite
def sql_start():
    global base, cur
    base = sq.connect('pizza_menu.db')
    cur = base.cursor()
    
    if base:
        print('connect to database - successful')

    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS menu(img TEXT, name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, description TEXT, price TEXT)')
    base.commit()


async def sql_add_command(state):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO menu VALUES (?,?,?,?)', tuple(data.values()))
        base.commit()


async def sql_read(message):
    for ret in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM menu').fetchall():
        await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, ret[0], f'{ret[1]}\nОписание: {ret[2]}\nЦена {ret[-1]}')


async def sql_read2():
    return cur.execute('SELECT * FROM menu').fetchall()

#отображаются все объекти
@dp.message_handler(text=['Меню'])
async def pizza_menu_command(message : types.Message):
    await sqlite_db.sql_read(message)
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp С помощью UPDATE обновляем данные.

Answer (score 0):

Общение с телеграм - это один слой логики.

Общение с базой данных - другой слой логики.

FSM служит для хранения состояний, а не для работы с базой данных

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать ORM для работы с бд, к примеру Django ORM или SQLAlchemy